# Leaflet: how to display lat/lng next to mouse cursor?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to display the current lat/lng on a map immediately next to the mouse (hand) cursor in Leaflet in . This option should also be toggleable as on/off.

One option would be to define a css box which would be displayed on top of the map next to the cursor (the box would be visible only when the toggle is on). The box would need to display the current lat/lng as well as move along with the cursor.

Not sure how to do this in practice and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a handler that opens/closes a popup on mouseover/mouseout and updates it on mousemove:

```js
L.CursorHandler = L.Handler.extend({

    addHooks: function () {
        this._popup = new L.Popup();
        this._map.on('mouseover', this._open, this);
        this._map.on('mousemove', this._update, this);
        this._map.on('mouseout', this._close, this);
    },

    removeHooks: function () {
        this._map.off('mouseover', this._open, this);
        this._map.off('mousemove', this._update, this);
        this._map.off('mouseout', this._close, this);
    },
    
    _open: function (e) {
        this._update(e);
        this._popup.openOn(this._map);
    },

    _close: function () {
        this._map.closePopup(this._popup);
    },

    _update: function (e) {
        this._popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent(e.latlng.toString());
    }

    
});

L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'cursor', L.CursorHandler);

var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    cursor: true,
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ]
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above example the handler is enabled by default through the `cursor` option of L.Map which get created by the handler:

```
var map = new L.Map(..., {
    cursor: true
});
```

If you leave out that option it's disabled by default and you can enable/disable it through methods of `map.cursor`:

```
map.cursor.enable();
map.cursor.disable();
```

You can wrap that in a simple control button or something and you're done.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for taking the time to create a fully working demo :)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get this working. Do you know by any chance how to stop the map from panning when the cursor is placed near the edge of the map?

Answer (score 0):

Use:new L.Popup({autoPan : false});

*this._popup = new L.Popup();*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).